# How can I associate a new Ubuntu Server with a Virtual Network on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-network

I've launched an Ubuntu VM on [azure](/questions/tagged/azure), and set it's `REGION/AFFINITY GROUP/VIRTUAL NETWORK` to an affinity group that I created.

---

[image: virtual network configuration]

But unfortunately it's getting a random IP address outside my specified network (10.175.174.xx).

Why would this be, and what do I need to do differently to get this server on my virtual network?

---

### Edit:

Today I tried creating a brand new VM using Ubuntu Server and discovered that I can associate the VM with an affinity group, but not with a Virtual Network. This is probably where I went wrong before.  So the new question is...

"How can I associate a new Ubuntu Server with a Virtual Network on Windows Azure?"

---

Here's a screenshot of the relavent setup with **Ubuntu**

[image]

And here's the EXACT SAME dropdownlist when setup on **Windows Server**

[image]

Comment: where do you see this address? on the portal or in your VM?

Comment: I'm seeing it within the portal.

Comment: I'm also seeing it in the terminal when I log in.  `IP address for eth0: 10.175.174.xx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit (two days) of digging, I was able to get in touch with an Azure expert on twitter.

> [Michael Washam ‏@MWashamMS](https://twitter.com/MWashamMS/status/289776247737835520)
>   @ChaseFlorell @SyntaxC4 @WindowsAzure The portal doesn't support deploying Linux VMs into a VNET (yet). You have to use cli (PS or Node)

The result is quite simple, use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

```
# From Get-AzureVMImage 
$img = 'b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_04_1-LTS-amd64-server-20121218-en-us-30GB'
$user = 'somelinuxuser'
$pass = 'somelinuxpwd!'
$vnet = 'HybridVNET'
$ag = 'WestUSAG'
$svcname = 'mylinuxsvc1' 

New-AzureVMConfig -Name 'linuxfromps1' -ImageName $img -InstanceSize Small |
    Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser $user -Password $pass |
    Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames 'AppSubnet' | # Optional 
    New-AzureVM -ServiceName $svcname -VNetName $vnet -AffinityGroup $ag
```

[reference](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/01/11/how-to-provision-a-linux-vm-in-a-vnet-with-powershell/)